# Recursive convert a 3-tuple to a char - Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Given this function, I was wondering how one would approach this problem

```
convertChar' :: [[(Int, Int, Int)]] -> [[Char]]
```

I have the following helper functions, not sure if they're needed

```
toList :: [[(Int, Int, Int)]] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
toList [(x)] = (x)

convertList :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> [[(Int, Int, Int)]]
convertList x = [x]
```

The `(Int, Int, Int)` will either be `(1, 1, 1) or (0, 0, 0)`

- If the tuple is (1, 1, 1) it will return the █ char.
- If the tuple is   (0, 0, 0) it will return " "

I was wondering what the smart way to approach this is.
Would I have to convert the original input from [[()]] to [()]
Apply the functions and then convert back to [[()]] before calling the converChar function recursively again?

Comment: You should not vandalize your question. Instead of editing and removing the content (which will be restored by the moderators, anyway), you can _close_ it yourself. Or alternatively, you can answer your own question, if you know how to solve your issue. Note that when a question has an upvoted answer, it can no longer be deleted by SO rules (this does not apply here, so you can still close it yourself).

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I can come up with is that you should probably change your program so that your types represent what you want. Specifically, when I look at your code it seems that you have (or at least you think/you don’t have but wrote the wrong program):

1. Every `[[(Int,Int,Int)]]` is a list of the form `[xs]`
2. Every `(Int,Int,Int)` is either `(0,0,0)` or `(1,1,1)`

Firstly I will write down a solution to your problem as stated. Secondly I will show you how to construct types that represent the state of the wold (and don’t allow you to represent illegal states).

```
renderThing (0,0,0) = ' '
renderThing (1,1,1) = '█'
renderState = map (map renderThing)
```

Let’s describe this briefly. The first two lines define a partial function to do what your int-triple-to-char function, as described in the parent.

The third line defines the function you want. Let’s read it from left to right:

1. To `renderState` (which will have type `[[(Int,Int,Int)]] -> [[Char]]`):
2. Apply the `map renderThing :: [(Int,Int,Int)] -> [Char]` to each element of the list passed as input

   1. To do that function, apply `renderThing` to each element of the inner list (I assume this is a row)

Unfortunately your program will crash if you ever violate your implicit invariant that any `(Int,Int,Int)`  is either `(0,0,0)`, or `(1,1,1)`. One better type could be `(Bool,Bool,Bool)` as each element can then only have one of two values. Another way you could do this is:

```
data Thing = White | Black
```

There are two ways to put this into your program. Either use good types throughout so the compiler can make sure you never end up in an unexpected state, or you can have conversion functions which can have errors:

```
renderableBoard :: [[(Int,Int,Int)]] -> Either String [[Thing]]
renderableBoard = mapM (mapM convertOne) where
  convertOne (0,0,0) = White
  convertOne (1,1,1) = Black
  convertOne x = "cannot concert to thing: " ++ show x
```